# Opera and IE8 - gap below body

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, opera

At http://www.duncannz.com I have a problem that only occurs in <del>Opera</del> *Opera prior to v12.0* and IE 8. If you open either of those browsers, visit that website and try to scroll down... it will. Even though the body is only 100% width. When you scroll you see a gap that is part of the `<html>` element not the `<body>` element, judging by how that extra bit's background looks.

[image: opera problem]

Why the gap on the bottom in Opera when you scroll down? Also occurs in IE 8.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: It's not caused by that footer you see - if you visit a longer page like http://www.duncannz.com/pages/text-to-code.php and scroll down that gap is there.

EDIT 2: So this problem seems to be fixed in Opera 12, aswell as the `img border-radius` not working bug. But I was on an older version and I frequently `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. If I'm on an old version and have never been told about a new one I'm sure others are too. Plus still need IE 8 fix.

EDIT 3:

I've found the reason, but not quite the solution. I have a `box-shadow` (and [PIE](http://www.css3pie.com) workarounds) on my `body`. When you apply a blur to a `box-shadow`, the shadow expands. This expansion causes the shadow to dip below the body, and out of sight. However this glitch in older Opera versions, and in IE8, caused the blur of the shadow that was dipping below the body to not be out of sight, and instead create a scrollable area so you can see the whole `box-shadow`.

If that's unclear [here's a demo](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/) - set the first value - "Angle" to `0deg`, set the 3rd value - "Blur" to `0px` and look. Then increase the blur and you'll see the blur of the shadow dipping below the rectangle. Unfortunately on IE8 this blur creates a gap below the body (so user sees the whole blur)

If I remove the blur there is no scrollable area. However I want the blur - it looks horrible without.

How do I do this?

Comment: Which version of Opera? In my version (latest, v12) it displays as it should display.

Comment: @Styxxy I'm on Linux, with the latest version. EDIT: Or I thought it was the latest version

Comment: Hmm my `opera:about` screen shows version 11.10

Comment: OK I'm suprised that the Opera updates aren't in the repos (with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. But I've downloaded the newest deb manually now.

Comment: OK I can confirm that when I manually download Opera v12 it's fine. However still need a fix for older Opera versions, and for IE8.

Comment: @duncan12 for what is worth, Opera users upgrade their browsers very quickly in a timeframe of 3 months or so.

Comment: I just downloaded a copy of Opera 11.0 and it renders fine. (Win 7) EDIT: Actually the longer page displays fine, but the home page has the error.

Comment: Still battling with this problem in IE8...

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you have chosen

```
body {min-height: 100%;}
```

instead of

```
body {height: 100%;}
```

btw it still occurs sometimes in Opera 12.0 when you slowly resize the window. There are states where it is happening. I would say that it must hit something like a rounding error or so in the code.

I would also slightly increase the body padding only for the bottom.

Comment: It's min-height not height because if it's min-height  then longer pages have a huge gap below the body that shows the rest of the content (because the white body only fits 100% of the screen). If I increase the body padding on the top or bottom then pages become scrollable that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin of the hr:

```
hr.blackhr {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

More generally, what you need is a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, not on IE8 or old Opera versions at least... plus I need the margin.